# GPS in Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, routes, gps

I have an application with a Google map. I traced the routes with address history to follow to go from one point to another. I would like to implement GPS service on my map, like Google Maps application mobile, which will go running for both voice and by visualization. My APP is in HTML5 and in javascript, not in native.

Basically, I would like to do this with Google Maps Api or something like that:

[image]

Thank you and sorry about my english.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Google Maps API for the recommended use of directions https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

Alternatively if you have a Android / iOS App and want to open google directions through an intent, check the documentation for [Google Maps Intents](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents#overview) for Android or [Google Maps URL Scheme](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/urlscheme) for iOS respectively

Comment: I use this documentation but I need GPS service. I put a picture in question

Comment: There is a explanation of how GPS is used in maps, this might help you get Location data for your own App https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location#request_runtime_permissions

Comment: But with this documentation, I think, is not for do that I put in picture, no? :)

Comment: And I would like to do this in HTML5 not in native